# Error code 10022 (Invalid arugment) on WSALookupServiceBegin()

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, winsock

I'm currently attempting to do Bluetooth device discovery with the Window Winsock API. I am fairly new to C and C++ coding, so I apologize if I have any silly mistakes here.

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    int iResult;

    // Initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create query parameters
    WSAQUERYSETW querySet;
    memset(&querySet, 0, sizeof(querySet));
    querySet.dwSize = sizeof(querySet);
    querySet.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;

    // Create flags and handle
    DWORD flags = LUP_DEEP | LUP_RETURN_ALL;
    HANDLE handle;

    // Begin service lookup
    iResult = WSALookupServiceBeginW(&querySet, flags, &handle);
    if(iResult != 0) {
        printf("Failed to begin service lookup: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I have been looking all over for examples of using WinSock to do Bluetooth device discovery, however I have been completely unable to find any. I am certain I am simply using the wrong keywords in my search. However, when running this code it goes fine up until the actual call to `WSALookupServiceBeginW()`. When calling this method, I get an error code of 10022 which according to the Microsoft documentation means I have passed an invalid argument. However, I am unsure which argument is invalid. Is it my query parameters? My flags? My querySet?

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong in this specific block of code or knows a good place I can find information on how to use the WinSock API, I would also greatly appreciate that.

EDIT 1: I am not new to coding, just to C and C++ coding (and the Windows APIs in general). I wouldn't say I am an expert, but I would say I am fairly proficient in the Java programming language.

Comment: dwFlags = LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_FLUSHCACHE | LUP_RETURN_ADDR; (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin-for-device-inquiry)

Comment: For services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bluetooth/bluetooth-and-wsalookupservicebegin-for-service-discovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having is that I was using the wrong flags in the `WSALookupServiceBegin()` function. The flags should have contained the values of `LUP_CONTAINERS` and `LUP_FLUSH_CACHE`, but they did not. Thanks to the people in the comments for the solution and more information on how to better use Winsock! :)